# How to get variable's value in a lambda expression from outside the function in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin, scope

I'm trying to get the value of the variable "finalvalue" in order to use it in another function, but it's not visible/accessible from outside the "edittext.onClickListener()" function.

I tried to declare it as a companion object but still I couldn't make it.
Also, declaring it in main class makes it visible, but I want the updated value of this variable which is set in the "edittext.onClickListener()" function.

What am I missing? Thanks.

UPDATE: Some words about the program. It's just a simple Countdown timer. edittext.getText() takes the input (how many seconds), then convert it to Integer. In the next function named "startbutton.onClickListener" I multiply it by 1000 to convert it to seconds and start the countdown.
the problem is that I can't get the updated value of "finalvalue". I only have access to the initial value of the variable.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var finalvalue = 30

    val day_night=findViewById<Button>(R.id.day_night)
    val setbutton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.setbutton)
    val stopbutton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.stopbutton)
    val startbutton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.startbutton)
    val antistrofimetrisi=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.antistrofimetrisi)
    val edittext=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext)


    var edittextIsVisible = false
    antistrofimetrisi.setText("0")

    setbutton.setOnClickListener() {
        if(edittextIsVisible == false) {
            edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            edittextIsVisible = true }

        else {
            edittext.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            edittextIsVisible = false }

    }


    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener() { v, actionId, event ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE && edittext.getText().toString() == "")
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Εισάγετε έγκυρο αριθμό δευτερολέπτων", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            true
        }

        else

        {
            var value: String = edittext.getText().toString()
            var finalvalue = Integer.parseInt(value)
            antistrofimetrisi.setText(finalvalue.toString())
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Πιέστε START για αντίστροφη μέτρηση από τα " + finalvalue + " δευτερόλεπτα",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()



            false
        }
    }



    startbutton.setOnClickListener()
    {
        var secondsLeft: Int = 0
        var finalseconds = finalvalue*1000
        val timer = object: CountDownTimer(finalseconds.toLong(), 100) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

                if (Math.round(millisUntilFinished.toFloat() / 1000.0f) != secondsLeft)
                {
                    secondsLeft = Math.round(millisUntilFinished.toFloat() / 1000.0f)
                    antistrofimetrisi.setText(secondsLeft.toString())
                }



                var timeleft = millisUntilFinished / 1000
                antistrofimetrisi.setText(timeleft.toString()) }



            override fun onFinish() {
                antistrofimetrisi.setText("0")
                start()
            }
        }.start()


        stopbutton.setOnClickListener()
        {
            timer.cancel()
            antistrofimetrisi.setText("0")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you declare finalValue at the class level and not inside the listener?

Comment: I did, but I get the declaration value of this variable, and not the updated one which is set in the edittext.setOnEditorActionListener() function.

Comment: You will get the new value after it is changed inside the listener. If the code inside the listener is not executed, of course you will get the initial value.

Comment: It still gives me the initial value

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code, including where you define finalvalue outside the listener and how you make sure you access finalvalue _after_ the listener is called.

Comment: I added more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're *shadowing* the variable.  You've declared `var finalValue` twice - near the top of `onCreate` and inside the callback.  Inside the callback, you're updating the temporary variable which only exists in that scope.  The outer variable is never updated.

You do not have a variable at the class level.  The outermost version is only defined within the scope of `onCreate`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // this is not a good variable name, since the variable is not final 
    // in the programming sense or in any other sense of the word
    var finalValue = 30   

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        // ...

        edittext.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->

            // ...

            var value: String = edittext.getText().toString()

            // note that I'm not re-declaring with "var" here
            finalvalue = Integer.parseInt(value)

            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

If I could give some other advice:

1. Format your code properly.  Use the auto-format feature of Android Studio.  What you have here looks kind of like a C-style, but this is Kotlin, so...
2. Break up your code.  The reason you ran into problems with this is because you just have one giant function which does everything.  Your callbacks should really just call a function, where that function is what performs all the logic.  Something like this:

```
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    editText.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
        onEditTextChanged(editText.getText())
    }
}

fun onEditTextChanged(text : String) {
    // all of the logic from the callback goes here
}
```

When your code is less jumbled, it's easier to see what the logic is.

Oftentimes, finding a bug within messy code is like finding something in a messy room.  If you want to find something, start picking up.  Then you're accomplishing two things at once.  As you clean, you'll find what you're looking for -- and you'll have a nice clean room!

Comment: You were right. It was shadowed. Thank you for the great answer, it's true, I prefer the C-style. I may have to make my code more organized. Thanks again.